# jQuery $.post function not hitting the server? failed error response

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to access a control processor that has a built in web server. Based on the specific values that are programmed into the controller I am able to trigger actions through a website that resides on its built in server using jQuery or js. I'm having an issue though with the jQuery post command. When I use goggle's REST plugin everything works and I successfully get a response.  Any ideas?

```
function GetVariableValuesByName(name) {
    $.post("http://10.10.254.11/RPC/", {
        method: "GetVariableValuesByName",
        param1: name,
        encoding: "2"
    }).done(function (data) {
        data = String(data);
        var info = data.responseText;
        alert(info);
    }).fail(function (data) {
        data = String(data);
        alert("error " + data)
    }).always(function (data) {
        data = String(data);
        alert("just in case " + data);
    });
}
```

Some additional examples the last function example assumes I've created the xmlhttp object.

```
function GetVariableValuesByName(name) {

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://10.10.254.11/RPC/",
data: { method: "GetVariableValueByName", param1: "VOL_BAR", encoding: "2" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
}).fail(function(msg) {
    alert("error " + msg)
});
}

function GetVariableValuesByName(name) {

xmlhttp.open("POST","http://10.10.254.11/RPC/",false);
var theString = "method=GetVariableValueByName&param1=" + name;
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader ("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(theString);    
var wacivar = xmlhttp.responseText; 
wacivar = String(wacivar);
wacivar = wacivar.substr(19);

alert(wacivar);
}
```

Comment: How are you confirming that it isn't hitting the server? no response or failed response doesn't necessarily mean it isn't hitting the server.

Comment: have you tried looking at the outbound traffic?

Comment: I'm sorry guys I've been working on this project for weeks and I'm tired.  The controller has a built in webserver but its slow so I offloaded my site to an apache box I had laying around my office.  Looks like there is a security issue with me running the commands from the apache box and calling the controller's built in server.  Any ideas around this?

Comment: The funny thing is that its only this function.  I have a few others that I'm calling in the exact same fashion that work perfectly.  This one is requesting variable info though while the others are posting an action.  The action occurs so I'm not requesting any callback.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @RoyJ we need a banner with "Same Origin Policy [link]" on Stack Overflow. This comes up at least once a day!

Comment: Thank you for the link Roy, can you give me a workaround example?  I have two other pieces of code that i've used successfully on teh origin server but they dont on teh apache server

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting the same-origin policy which means that you whilst you can make AJAX requests to another domain, you cannot read the response (that is why you callbacks are not firing). The solution here is to use either [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (adding extra headers to your HTTP responses on the server side) or [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (making a custom response with a JSONP callback). I'd advice you to use CORS as it provides better error handling, whilst JSONP is more of a hack.

If you want to use CORS, add the described headers in Wikipedia article to responses that must be cross-domain.

You asked for an example of the solution, but the solution must be implemented on the server side for both JSONP and CORS.

Comment: implemented how exactly?  is there a file or something I can place in the directory?  please excuse my ignorance

Comment: what is your server side language? php? in php you must set the HTTP headers for the response like described here http://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working/

Comment: On the built in server on the controller I don't have access to change any of the config files and I cannot run php on it.  I can add text files if need be such as an apcache file but thats pretty much it.  It will also do server side includes from .asp.  On the apache server its just an apache server.  Right now I dont have anything additional installed.

Comment: Sorry, if I confused you with PHP. As I understand, your server side language is ASP. Here's how you do it in ASP http://encosia.com/using-cors-to-access-asp-net-services-across-domains/